# Magento 1.9 excl. and incl. product price displaying same at checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

Currently I am having an issue for displaying same incl and excl at tax price. previously it was working fine but now it is not. I have not change any settings.

Please can anyone tell in which tables tax incl and excl prices are saved. So I can look into that.

It is working fine at catalog and details page i.e. both pages displaying the correct prices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no place for an "incl." price value. The result is a calculation. So What I understand is that your price results (with and without tax) is the same? Maybe you changed something (by mistake) in the checkout calculation. Have you checked the settings there?

Comment: No it is a very strange issue. For a few days everything works fine(all incl, excl prices) but then suddenly it started showing incl and excl price same. and apply double tax in grand total. So to fix this we just click on save button on sales->tax settings without changing any setting and then everything start working fine again. We are so confused why this happened and sure that it is not setting issue.

Comment: It happened in the interval of one or two days.

Comment: How many days?  How long it work fine? Maybe it changes during an Index progress. Could you delimit it on a certain time? Have you made an upgrade? Which Mag Version 1.X? Have you third Party module for any price calculation?

Comment: It is random. It can happened anytime. We have magento 1.9. We have an extension EU VAT enhanced. Also some caching extensions too.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Maybe there is something.

Comment: Hello I have found the issue. Its actually cache issue. In site there are two another cache modules: ves and varnish apart from magento default cache. Please see this I have updated it: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282306/cache-issue-in-magento-1