# Cache issue in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, full-page-cache

Hello I have used **ves and varnish full page cache extensions** for better speed performance

but it is creating some **issues now like my cart page is not showing all newly added product or showing old/wrong prices etc.**

So I want to know why is this happening and did I miss some configuration for VES module or I should disable it as it is creating an issue.

Also, I want to mention I have **All three caches enabled Magento default FPC, Varnish FPC and VES FPC.**

Is it causing an issue?

Thanks

Comment: I would disable cache on checkout

Comment: Yes I have set cache to null(with action property) for cart block which should make whole cart page uncacheable but still due to ves/varnish it is not making cache clean. I guess this is only affecting magento FPC.